# Resources for writers: websites for posting stories and poetry

Tags: publishing, short-story, self-publishing, poetry

I was asked if I could suggest a website (in English) where one can create a profile and post short-stories, poetry, or other pieces of literary work in an "informal" way. Additionally, such website should allow the writer to:

- edit the work (without the edits being visible) and eventually delete it at any time;
- receive some sort of feedback from a community (in the form of comments and "upvotes").

I know some good forums with good communities that I may suggest, but they don't fit the two additional requirements. Does any of you know some more fitting website?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Medium.com. Or Wattpad.com. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to smashwords. It is a complete platform where you can publish ebooks. It is even possible to ask money for buying your ebooks, if i am not mistaking.